# Could not read from the file with contents of 'stdout=file_object' in python

Tags: subprocess, stdout

I was trying to experiment with subprocess.Popen() constructor by using file object for the stdout. When I run the below code, the file gets created (with the contents) but contents are not displayed on the console. I cannot understand what I am missing. Can anyone please point out my mistake(if any)?

```
file_name = "abc.txt"
fo = open(file_name, 'w')
cmd = 'dir'
child = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=fo, stderr=fo, shell=True)
fo.close()

with open(file_name, 'r') as fo: print(fo.read())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait for subprocess finish before reading the content.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

file_name = "abc.txt"
fo = open(file_name, 'w')
cmd = 'dir'
child = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=fo, stderr=fo, shell=True)
child.wait()
fo.flush()
fo.close()

with open(file_name) as fo:
    print(fo.read())

# print (child.poll())
```